# string with full stop in it not properly outputted in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a Question model in my Ruby on Rails project with Postgresql database which has a string data type called question. (Original hey!) When I input some data with a full stop (.) in it, it doesn't print/output in my html/erb view file correctly, everything before the full stop is missing!

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label question.question %><br />
....
```

It is storing in my database correctly as per the below output from the psql console

```
select question from questions where "id"=1;
question
----------------------------------
 What is 2+3. What is the answer?
(1 row)
```

Does anyone know what is happening here (and the workaround)? I've tried things such as .html_safe and .to_s to no avail.

EDIT: also another thing that bothers me about the html output is that it gets rid of all my capitalized letters. Wtf?!

So the html output of the example about would be below...

```
what is the answer?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the disappearing text part, but the label helper applies the `humanize` method to auto-generated label text (i.e. if no explicit label text is passed in). In the console it looks like this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > helper.label_tag "All Caps String"
 => "<label for=\"All_Caps_String\">All caps string</label>"
```

As a workaround, try providing an explicit label value:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > helper.label_tag "All Caps String", "All Caps String"
 => "<label for=\"All_Caps_String\">All Caps String</label>
```

So try this:

```
<%= f.label question.question, question.question %>
```